# 404Error-Struts2 Example(Running well when test on pure jsp of Dynamic We Project 3.0 web module)

Tags: struts2, http-status-code-404

I follow this article http://java.dzone.com/articles/struts2-tutorial-part-27 to learn struts 2 and got 404 error on my tomcat server 7, i have tested 
another pure jsp of Dynamic We Project 3.0 web module on the same tomcat server 7, it works good. So what caused the error on struts example, since there are just few files in this example, so the first thing came in my mind is the deployment descriptor web.xml in struts 2 example, here is the original one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Struts2 Application</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>

            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

I found the difference, the original web module is 2.4, the one i created is 3.0, so i replaced

```
<web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

with

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
```

and restart the tomcat server, think may solve the problem, but i still got the error, so i got confused since there are no more particular files have relationship to the server, can some expert help me?

Here is the struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation"
        value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />

    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
        value="ApplicationResources" />

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">

        <action name="login"
            class="net.viralpatel.struts2.LoginAction">
            <result name="success">Welcome.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">Login.jsp</result>

        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: is there any exception trace on server console??

Comment: Not enough information to go on. In addition to the logs, you need to post the relevant portion of your `struts.xml` config file, the URL you're trying to access, etc.

Comment: more information is needed to provide any inputs especially config files

Comment: @dave newton: i updated the struts.xml, please check http://java.dzone.com/articles/struts2-tutorial-part-27 if you think i told little information.

Comment: @user1055108 Set `devMode` to true as well while troubleshooting. Update the filter, make sure you have all the library dependencies, tell us if there's anything in the logs, and tell us what URL you're trying to hit, and what your web app's context is.

Comment: @user1055108 see my updated post it seems you have not configured namespace correctly

Answer (score 2):

Check the `web.xml` as well as the deployment descriptor created by Eclipse to know if it points to the correct JSP. i.e. if the jsp is under JSP folder, the welcome file should be `/JSP/welcome.jsp`

Answer (score 0):

`404` is generally means `page not found` but with this little information its very hard to say whats is going wrong.

is there any exception/error coming on the server console if there is any show it up.
As a side note to learn or get started with struts2 my best shot would be to download sample application from [struts2 official site](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi#struts231-SNAPSHOT) and run them inside your tomcat.

this will help you to understand struts2 layout as well other required configurations.

FYI: `Filter dispatcher` has been deprecated in struts2 i must suggest you to use

```
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
```

its always better to start with updated one

**edit**

URL which you are trying to hit is still missing from the post but it seems a problem of namespace as you have defined namespace in your package and as per this struts2 will try to resolve your namespace hirarchy which in your case it is not able to find.
read namespace for details
[Struts2 Name Spaces](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/namespace-configuration.html)

Additionally paste your jsp code also just to cross check remove this line `namespace="/"` from your struts configuration file and check it should work

Comment: Still not working, i updated the struts.xml, can you take a look

Comment: i know what 404 means, and there is no exception/error coming, the other web project works fine, just this one says not found, must something wrong with the configuration, i updated the struts.xml, can you take a look, thanks!

Comment: @DᴀᴠᴇNᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ i am still not able to understand this namespace convept of struts2 so i believe that if the action he is hitting is not defined in the name space "/" it should fall back to default namespace "" and there should be action in default namespace.correct me if i am wrong